# Does OpenLayers support right to left languages?

Tags: openlayers-2, internationalization

[Right to Left languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) need to be handled differently. For instance, in popups the text and the close box should be reversed. Google Maps [supports](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics?hl=en#Language) this if the page has a `<html dir='rtl'>` element, how about OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

I set up a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nachtigall/jG83a/) where I got it working using a bit CSS and `dir='rtl'`. Unfortunately, it needs a few CSS `!important` overrides.